# Trying to return value from Message c++ mfc

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

i'm using c++ mfc and declare message in my dlg:

```
LRESULT CMyWnd2::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wParam=5;
    lParam=6;
    return 0;
}
```

using code:

```
WPARAM w=0;
LPARAM l=0;
SendMessage(hwnd,messageId,w,l);
cout<<w<<l<<endl;
```

print:

```
0
0
```

how can i change the values of w / l parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What 'value' do you want to return? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: iwm trying to update the value of WPARAM/LPARAM

Comment: No, it's still not clear. Please expand by editing the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @LitalKapara, unless `wParam` and `lParam` reference an object you can't 'update' those parameters directly. That doesn't make sense. My guess is you're trying to tell some control or some dialog something.

Comment: i'm editing my question

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz, i want to pass data from DLG class to another class by using message callback

Comment: @LitalKapara, see my answer below. For more complex types (classes) pass a pointer to the class in `lParam`.

Comment: Why don't you use the return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LRESULT CMyWnd2::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    *((WPARAM*)wParam)=5;
    *((LPARAM*)lParam)=6;
    return 0;
}


WPARAM w=0;
LPARAM l=0;
SendMessage(hwnd,messageId,(WPARAM)&w,(LPARAM)&l);
cout<<w<<l<<endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

A function can not change the parameters passed in by value.

However, you can pass a pointer to whatever data structure you want in LPARAM, and modify that data structure in your message handler.

Here is how you can use it:

```
int myValueToBeUpdated = 0;
SendMessage(hwnd, messageId, 0, (LPARAM)&myValueToBeUpdated);
cout << myValueToBeUpdated << endl;
```

and the message handler:

```
LRESULT CMyWnd2::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int* p = (int*)lParam;
    *p = 42;
    return 0;
}
```