# Return value of WinMain

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Sup all, I've a question about WinMain. In VS2010, the return value of _tWinMain is "(int) msg.wParam". I don't understand why it returns wParam.

What is wParam? Can I just change it to "return 0"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394583/trying-to-return-value-from-message-c-mfc

Comment: Presumably there's also code for a standard Windows message loop that exits that loop when a WM_QUIT message is processed. In that case `msg.wParam` has the exit value that was passed in the message and that WinMain is supposed to return.

Comment: That's just the template project that VS creates automatically. You can change it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `WM_QUIT` is processed by `GetMessage`, it terminates the message loop. The documentation for [`WM_QUIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632641.aspx) says this:

> **wParam**
>
> The exit code given in the PostQuitMessage function.

This is the value that you are returning from `WinMain`. This value is therefore just the value that was passed as the exit code to `PostQuitMessage`.

You can change the code to return whatever you want, zero if you wish. However, in normal termination, `PostQuitMessage` will be passed zero so there is nothing much to be gained by making such a change.

Answer (score 1):

value returned from `WinMain` will be passed as is to [ExitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx) function.
c/c++ run-time or [ExitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx) itself not interpret and use *uExitCode* - so you can use absolute any value  (only may be return `STILL_ACTIVE` not nice but even return it not error) - this is your application and you need decide yourself what code you need return. this code can retrieve another application by call [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) - and somehow interpret it , if *uExitCode* from your application containing some information (*usual this is used as error code and 0 mean no error*). however in most case *uExitCode* not containing any info and nobody interesting  in your return code - so absolute no different what value you return. return `msg.wParam` of course also possible but no more sense than return 0 or say `__LINE__`